# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3n+2}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What do you think ?

Thanks for your time.

[image: pic]

Comment: Are you asking us to check whether your solution is correct?

Comment: Is that sum is meant to be from $n = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
let $x=1$
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
$$e-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\tag1$$
$$(e^x)'=e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$
$$xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n}}{n!}$$
let $x=1$
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}$$
$$e=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}\tag2$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3n+2}{n!}=3e+2(e-1)=5e-2$$

Answer (score 0):

As you deduced correctly, we should rewrite everything in terms of $\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n !}$; however, you made an error with the index in the part with $\frac{2}{n!}$. Basically, you included $\frac{2}{0!}$ in your result while this term is not present in the original sum.

Answer (score 0):

We can use that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3n+2}{n!}=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=$$

$$=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}-2=5e-2$$